# Azure web apps auto-swap notifications

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy, azure-deployment-slots

I'm using a deployment slot called `warmup` on my Azure web app with the auto-swap feature. My deployment process is as follows:

1. Octopus Deploy creates a release and deploys to the `warmup` slot
2. Auto-swap warms up the slot and swaps to `production` as soon as the app is warmed up

**Is there a way to get notified when an auto-swap operation finishes?** I'd like to get notified both when the operation succeeds or when it fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add post-deployment web hooks via the kudu site: `https://<yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net/WebHooks`

I don't think this will notify you of the swap, but it'll at least let you know the deployment completed successfully.

You can find more details here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/04/receive-webhooks-from-azure-alerts-and-kudu-azure-web-app-deployment.aspx

If you'd like to get notified of an auto-swap operation specifically you can submit a feature request here: 
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. I created a [feature request](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/10217241-add-a-web-hook-to-get-notified-of-completed-auto-s).